# JQuery - Not Hiding the right number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code for producing a button control panel. It is placed side by side with a carousel of images and is made to have a maximum of the same height. If it is higher, buttons are hidden one by one until the control panel and the carousel are the same height. If buttons are hidden it adds a "More Button" to later reveal these buttons. The problem is that it is deleting one extra button resulting in the attached image. All buttons are the same width and height. Can anyone point out the problem in the script?

```
function removeExtraButtons()
{
    jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
    var count = 0;
    $('.contbut').reverse().each(function(){
        if($('.dealscontrol').outerHeight() <= $('#carousel-featured-deal').outerHeight())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('hidecontbut');
            $('.dealscontrol').css('height','auto');
            count = count + 1;
        }
    });
    $('.dealscontrol').css('height',$('#carousel-featured-deal').height());
    if(count == 0)
    {
        $('#cont-more').addClass('hidecontbut');    
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the HTML for the button section:

```
<div class="dealscontrol col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-pull-10 col-md-pull-9 col-sm-pull-8 col-xs-pull-0 featcol" style="height: 350px;">
   <form id="dealcontrolform" action="/deals" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <div>
         <div class="form-type-select form-item-home-hub form-item form-group">
            <label for="edit-home-hub"><span class="controltext">Travel Hub</span> </label>
            <select onchange="this.form.submit();" class="form-control form-select" id="edit-home-hub" name="home_hub">
               <option value="1" selected="selected">New York</option>
               <option value="2">San Francisco</option>
               <option value="3">Chicago</option>
               <option value="4">Miami</option>
               <option value="5">Washington DC</option>
               <option value="6">Los Angeles</option>
               <option value="7">Boston</option>
               <option value="8">Seattle</option>
               <option value="9">Houston</option>
               <option value="10">Dallas</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-type-checkboxes form-item-triptype form-item form-group">
            <label for="edit-triptype"><span class="controltext">Trip Type</span> </label>
            <div id="edit-triptype" class="form-checkboxes control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline">
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-triptype-air-package form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-triptype-air-package" name="triptype[air_package]" value="air_package" checked="checked">  
                  <label for="edit-triptype-air-package">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Air-Inclusive Packages">
                        <div class="controlairinclusive controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-triptype-hotel-only form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-triptype-hotel-only" name="triptype[hotel_only]" value="hotel_only" checked="checked">  
                  <label for="edit-triptype-hotel-only">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Only Hotel">
                        <div class="controlhotel controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-triptype-cruise form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-triptype-cruise" name="triptype[cruise]" value="cruise" checked="checked">  
                  <label for="edit-triptype-cruise">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Cruises">
                        <div class="controlcruise controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-type-checkboxes form-item-tripextras form-item form-group">
            <label for="edit-tripextras"><span class="controltext">Extras</span> </label>
            <div id="edit-tripextras" class="form-checkboxes control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline">
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-wine form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-wine" name="tripextras[wine]" value="wine">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-wine">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Wine">
                        <div class="controlwine controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-food form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-food" name="tripextras[food]" value="food">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-food">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Food">
                        <div class="controlfood controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-ski form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-ski" name="tripextras[ski]" value="ski">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-ski">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Ski">
                        <div class="controlski controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-dance form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-dance" name="tripextras[dance]" value="dance">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-dance">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Dance">
                        <div class="controldance controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-spa form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-spa" name="tripextras[spa]" value="spa">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-spa">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Spa">
                        <div class="controlspa controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-tours form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-tours" name="tripextras[tours]" value="tours">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-tours">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tours">
                        <div class="controltours controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-all-inclusive form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-all-inclusive" name="tripextras[all_inclusive]" value="all_inclusive">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-all-inclusive">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="All Inclusive">
                        <div class="controlall_inclusive controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-gambling form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-gambling" name="tripextras[gambling]" value="gambling">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-gambling">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Gambling">
                        <div class="controlgambling controlpanelbutton contbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-family form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-family" name="tripextras[family]" value="family">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-family">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Family">
                        <div class="controlfamily controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-exotic form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-exotic" name="tripextras[exotic]" value="exotic">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-exotic">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Exotic">
                        <div class="controlexotic controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-shopping form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-shopping" name="tripextras[shopping]" value="shopping">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-shopping">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Shopping">
                        <div class="controlshopping controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-culture form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-culture" name="tripextras[culture]" value="culture">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-culture">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Culture">
                        <div class="controlculture controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-romance form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-romance" name="tripextras[romance]" value="romance">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-romance">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Romance">
                        <div class="controlromance controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-tripextras-beach form-item checkbox">
                  <input class="control-box container-inline trip_extra form-inline form-checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" id="edit-tripextras-beach" name="tripextras[beach]" value="beach">  
                  <label for="edit-tripextras-beach">
                     <div class="checkicon-yes" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Beach">
                        <div class="controlbeach controlpanelbutton contbut hidecontbut"></div>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="cont-more">More</div>
         <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-2bAs7cV2I9h6l4aHSS5j2-0DRXSwIPR2JQ1zeGrsMFY">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="Z6UGQzTTLDzYfL1tQY3mceRW8tk4DDEMsirFwQAuGgQ">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="deals_control_form">
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the html for the button panel too?

Comment: can you share the necessary html part ?

Comment: are all images with the same height?

Comment: I've added the HTML. All images have the same dimensions as they come from a css sprite.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?  I tried making one based on the code that you posted, and it [completely freaks out when I click the checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/wutpn0ur/).